# Xubuntu 20.04 only boots on recovery mode

Tags: boot, drivers, grub2, intel-graphics

I am running xubuntu 20.04 on a Lenovo Ideapad 500. Since a couple of kernel updates I am facing issues while booting. If I boot after having normally shut down the computer, a black screen holds and nothing happens. If I boot again, appears a booting menu. Everything boots normally if I then select the recovery mode. Sporadically, however, it manages to boot normally on the first attempt. I would like to not be compelled to use the recovery mode any time I want to successfully turn on the computer.

After having looked quite a while online, I have started to suspect a graphic card issue. The laptop has two graphic cards (Intel and NVIDIA). When I list the hardware with the `lshw` command, the Intel graphic card appears *UNCLAIMED*, which I believe to be related with an issue with the driver. `i965-va-driver-shaders` is nonetheless installed. The NVIDIA's one is correctly listed with the corresponding proprietary driver.

What can I try to identify the root cause and solve the problem?

Comment: Just saying, that I have exactly the same problem on Lenovo T460s.